# Calculating a function and storing them as different variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

This is a general question regarding Python.

I would like to perform a function that does some calculations given a few input variables. But I have several input variables for which I need to perform the above function and finally store them as new variables, preferably with different names.

Example:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    do some calculation
    result = the above calculation
```

Now suppose I have 10 different pairs of `a,b,c,` how do I do the above calculation and store them by giving **10 different variable names,** i.e.

```
var1 = result of calculation of a1,b1,c1
var2 = result of calculation of a2,b2,c2
```

and so on

I know that I can manually repeat the calculation by writing the calculation part several times and store them separately. **This will make my code look very lengthy!** Also this makes me get confused with the several different names I should create!

Comment: Simply store results in a list.

Comment: could you please elaborate? I need the final results also for plotting them separately. It is the naming that I get confused with, i.e. how to create a loop that gives them different names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = [
    (a1, b1, c1),
    (a2, b2, c2),
    (a3, b3, c3)
]

results = [func(*args) for args in data]   # becomes [result1, result2, result3]
```

Comment: is there a way to name the final `results`? i.e. give them names, so that when needed later, we know the corresponding input variables that belong to the corresponding `result`. ?

Comment: @ThePredator: Why name them? The result for `data[0]` is in `results[0]`.